# Embedding of $K(\alpha)\hookrightarrow \bar{K}$ fixing $K$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $K(\alpha)/K$ be a finite separable extension of fields and let $\bar K$ be the alegbric closure of $K$.

Which embeddings $\beta:K(\alpha)\hookrightarrow \bar K$ fix $K$ (that is $\beta(k)=k,\forall k\in K$)?

Comment: Hint: where can $\alpha$ be sent via the embedding? Why does this determine the embedding?

Comment: @GalPorat intuitively $\beta(\alpha)=\alpha$  but how does that determine the embedding?

Comment: @Curvature : not necessarily : how many $\mathbb{R}$-automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ do you know ? Note that $\mathbb{C}= \mathbb{R}(i)$

Comment: @Max do you mean when $K=\mathbb{R},\alpha=i$? In this case there are 4 ($1\mapsto\pm1,\pm i$). Isn't it?

Comment: @GalPorat so $\alpha$ has to be mapped to $\alpha^{j}$ with $1\le j\le [K(a):K]$-1?

Comment: @Curvature : No, $1$ has to be sent to $1$, since $1\in \mathbb{R}$. But you are right that $i\to i$, and $i\to -i$ do give 2 automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ that fix $\mathbb{R}$ (here it's the special case where $K(\alpha) = \overline{K}$). And it does not have to be $\alpha^j$. To give you another hint (unless you want someone to give the full solution), have you heard of minimal polynomials ?

Comment: @Max I heard as I'm trying to learn some Galois theory. As far as I understand the minimal polynomial of this extension is $m_\alpha(x)=x^n-\alpha$ with $n=[K(\alpha):K]$. How does that help here?

Comment: No that's not the minimal polynomial. Take a look at the example I gave. The minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $X^2 +1$. But for any field morphism $f$, $f(i)^2 + 1 = f(i^2+1) = 0$, and so $f(i)$ is a root of $X^2 +1$. But the roots of this are $i$ and $-i$, so $f(i) = i$ or $-i$. Can you generalize this ? (I could write an answer but it wouldn't be full, since I don't know enough Galois theory to answer as precisely as maybe you'd want me to)

Comment: @Max So what you're saying is that $m(\beta(\alpha))$ has to zero and therefore there are exactly $[K(\alpha):K]$ embeddings, each defined by $\beta(1)=1,\beta(\alpha)\in\{\text{roots of the minimal polynomial}\}$?

Comment: Yes precisely. I'll write an answer to make that precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments, if $\beta$ is such a morphism, then it's fixed on $K$ and only the value of $\beta(\alpha)$ determines the morphism, but $\beta(\alpha)$ has to be a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

First of all, for the definitions, remember that since $K(\alpha)$ is by assumption a finite extension, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, and so the ideal $\{P \in K[X] \mid P(\alpha)=0\}$ is non zero, and since $K[X]$ is principal, it has a unique unitary generator $\pi_\alpha$, called the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. For any morphism $\beta: K \to L$ where $L$ is any field containing $K$, $\pi_\alpha(\beta(\alpha))=0$.

Note also that $\pi_\alpha$ is irreducible: indeed if $\pi_\alpha= PQ$, then $P(\alpha)=0$ or $Q(\alpha)=0$ since $K$ is a field, and thus if both $deg(Q), deg(P)\geq 1$, this contradicts the minimality of $\pi_\alpha$.

Now let $\gamma$ be any root of $\pi_\alpha$. We first note that $\pi_\gamma= \pi_\alpha$. Indeed since $\pi_\alpha$ cancels $\gamma$, $\pi_\gamma \mid \pi_\alpha$ by definition of minimal polynomial. However $\pi_\alpha$ is irreducible and both these polynomials are unitary so $\pi_\alpha= \pi_\gamma$. This will be helpful for what follows.

Define $f: K[X] \to \overline{K}$ by $f(P)= P(\gamma)$. Then by definition $Ker(f) = (\pi_\gamma)$ (the ideal generated by $\pi_\gamma$), and so by the first isomorphism theorem, $f$ factors through the canonical surjection $h: K[X] \to K[X]/(\pi_\gamma)$, which gives an injective morphism $g: K[X]/(\pi_\gamma) \to \overline{K}$. This morphism obviously fixes $K$.

Moreover $\pi_\gamma = \pi_\alpha$ so that $K[X]/(\pi_\gamma) = K[X]/(\pi_\alpha)$. But $s: K[X]/(\pi_\alpha) \to K(\alpha)$ defined by $s(k + (\pi_\alpha))= k$ for $k\in K$, and $s(X+(\pi_\alpha))= \alpha$ is an isomorphism that fixes $K$.

So in the end, putting $\beta := g\circ s^{-1}$ we get an injective morphism $K(\alpha) \to \overline{K}$ that fixes $K$, and such that $\beta(\alpha)=\gamma$.

To sum up, embeddings $\beta: K(\alpha) \to \overline{K}$ that fix $K$ are uniquely determined by the value of $\beta(\alpha)$, and there is such an embedding where $\beta(\alpha)$ is any of the roots of $\pi_\alpha$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, and these are the only such embeddings.